# Using replace() instead of xsl:analyze-string for a regex XSLT 2 3

Tags: xslt-2.0, regex-group, xpath-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have an `xsl:analyze-string()` with a regular expression that works as desired.

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="'file:/D:/workspace/projects/Original/img/star.jpg'" regex="([^.]*$)">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
   </xsl:matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
```

Returns the correct result:

`jpg`

However, instead of using `xsl:analyze-string()` I would like to use `replace()` (this gives an error: `The regular expression must not be one that matches a zero-length string`)

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('file:/D:/workspace/projects/Original/img/star.jpg', '([^.]*$)', '$1')"/>
```

I have another `analyze-string` expression, this one works as a `replace()`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('file:/D:/workspace/projects/Original/img/star.jpg', '^.*Original/(.*)$', '$1')"/>
```

It returns `img/star.jpg` which is the desired result.

Comment: Well, do you expect any input where using `replace($input, '([^.]+$)', '$1')` (i.e. with `+` instead of `*`) could give the wrong result? If you always have file names and you need that suffix then it shouldn't matter whether you match with `+` or `*`.

Comment: `([^.]+$)` works in `analyze-string`, but `<xsl:value-of select="replace($uri, '([^.]+$)', '$1')"/>` is returning the entire input string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `*` is the only obstacle preventing your attempt to work, I think you rather want e.g. `replace('file:/D:/workspace/projects/Original/img/star.jpg', '.*?([^.]+)$', '$1')`, i.e. for `replace` you have to match on more than the part you want to output.